# A ratio connected to the distribution of primes

Tags: prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

According to the Prime Number Theorem, a number $n$, roughly speaking, has probability of primality $\sigma_n:=1/\ln n$.

As every schoolchild learns, one can test the primality of $n$ by looking for divisibility by  primes up to $\sqrt{n}$.
If these divisibility tests enjoyed independence, one would get ``probability of primality" equal to
$$ \tau_n:=\prod_{p\leq \sqrt{n}} \frac{p-1}{p}\ .$$

Probability interpretations aside, one can examine the ratio $\sigma_n/\tau_n$.  What limit, if any, does it approach?  And how fast?

Comment: See the [Mertens theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems) as usual the optimal asymptotic depends on the Riemann hypothesis. If your question is if we find $\pi(x) \approx \frac{x}{\ln x}$ from $\prod_{n \le \sqrt{x}} (1-n^{-1})^{\pi(n) - \pi(n-1)} \approx \frac{\pi(x)}{x}$ the answer is yes. Making $\approx$ precise should give the Mertens theorem.

Comment: theorem 429 in Hardy and Wright, the product for primes $p \leq t$ of your $(p-1)/p$  is about $e^{- \gamma}/ \log t$  This is due o Mertens